# why does fmt.Printf swap rows?

Tags: go, printf

I recently started learning Golang and I don't have much programming experience. I ran into a problem while learning the for loop and the Math.Pow.(Tour of Go) function. Can someone explain why in this loop the second row (3, 3, 20) is counted first, and only then it counts the first (3, 2, 10). Moreover, a limit is also attributed to him. I would be very grateful if someone could clarify.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    // can't use v here, though
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
    )
}

// Output:
// 27 >= 20
// 9 20
```

I expected the output of the program to look like this.

```
9
27>=20
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Can you please copy and paste the _text_ of your examples, rather than screen captures ? this is the preferred way on SO -- text is searchable, indexable, copy-pastable ...

Comment: Do you mean that I write the program as text?

Comment: Println cannot be called before its arguments are computed. During this computation "27 >= 20" is printed. There is no loop in this program.

Comment: @JimB I just didn't know how i should do it right, sorry

Comment: There is no loop here, the function is called in the order the program is evaluated. https://go.dev/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation

Comment: @Peter ok, i got it. But  why it's 20 near 9 ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `pow(3, 2, 10)` returns 9 and `pow(3, 3, 20)` returns 20, so the Println call becomes `fmt.Println(9, 20)`.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments of Println are evaluated from left-to-right, so your call

```
fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
)
```

effectively becomes:

```
fmt.Println(
        9,
        20,
)
```

But in addition to that, second call to `pow` (that returned 20) called `Printf` on it's own ("27>=20"), so the result that you got is actually well-defined and expected.